# Java PhantomReference is not getting enqued

Tags: java, reference, garbage-collection

I am trying to understand the workings of PhantomReferences in Java and wrote this program for that.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

    final ReferenceQueue refQueue = new ReferenceQueue();
    Employer emp = new Employer();
    emp.setName("John");
    PhantomReference<Employer> phantom = new PhantomReference<Employer>(emp, refQueue);
    List referenceList = new ArrayList();
    referenceList.add(phantom);

    Thread th = new Thread(new Runnable(){

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                PhantomReference ref =  (PhantomReference) refQueue.remove();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }                        
        }                
    });
    th.start();

    for (int i = 0; i < 50000000; i++) {                
        if(i==(50000000-1)){
            Thread.sleep(10000);
            System.out.println(i);
            System.out.println("setting emp to null ");
            emp=null;
            System.gc();
        }                
    } 
}
```

But here I dont see the reference getting enqued as mentioned in the java API docs.
Am I missing something here?

Comment: 1. You should have posted the code here. 2. The code doesn't make a lot of sense to me. You have an empty loop, then Thread.sleep, then null-out reference, then GC, and immediately quit. The other thread will have no time to be notified.

Comment: Since refQueue.remove() is a blocking call the program will never quit until enqued.

Comment: That's a good point; try to simply add *two* `System.gc()` calls, see what happens.

Comment: I even tried with a verbose GC and I see the GC is getting triggered after setting the reference to null,but it is not getting enqueued.

Comment: That doesn't matter, there are many concerns to a GC run and not all of them happen in the same run. You must be aware that you are probing into the unspecified behavior of one specific JVM implementation.

Answer (score 1):

This is a duplicate... but I can't find the original.

In short: It *will* be enqueued... one day or another. Not immediately. Maybe after the next GC run, maybe next week. There's no guarantee concerning the timing.

Comment: +1 And, if all other threads are dead, then it will never happen if it didn't right away.